# Evolution Snooze Button Greyed out

Tags: 14.04, evolution, calendar

I have my Evolution Calendar set for reminders. It sent my alert today, but the Snooze options were greyed out. I see there are some other questions about items greying out, but they are mentioning apps that I am not having this problem in, so I think maybe this is a different issue.

Anyway, I just upgraded to 14.04, so I have some issues to work though. :(